# How to highlight a div with children (with partial opacity layer?) Like Yahoo mail, see pic

Tags: html, css

In Yahoo mail, when you are writing an email and you drag a file onto the page and hover, the message area becomes highlighted.  It can be seen here: [image: yahoo mail while drag-hovering a file over it]

The part of this that I don't get is how to have the blue area appear with partial opacity over the things under it that are normally visible.

With:

```
#blueBox {
background-color: #FFD090;
opacity: 0.0;
}
```

If the msgContent is a child of blueBox:

```
<div id='msgBox'>
   <div id='blueBox'>
      <div id='msgContent'>
       ... all the message contents, buttons, etc.
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and when msgBox is hovered I increase blueBox opacity from 0 to say 0.6, the blueBox will show but the msgContent div is hidden until the hover event.  It should be visible always.

If the msgContent div is not a child of blueBox, then the blueBox doesn't cover it.

I've tried rgba (http://jsfiddle.net/mkasson/nJcxQ/19/) like [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464845/how-to-set-opacity-on-container-div-and-not-on-children-text), but it doesn't cover over the child elements.

Couldn't do my usual watching/inspecting via browser's webdev tools because focus was never on the browser while dragging the file onto it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would go about this,

(What the problem is, you are using the parents background. You can't make the parents background go over it's content, that is not what a background does. It merely sites behind everything it is containing and acts as a background.)

html,

```
<div class="messageContent">
    <span class="overlay"></span>
    <p>Darn fanatically far and tarantula jeepers meek a secret much so hence underneath monogamously interwove apart gosh spilled far where and badger.</p>
    <a href="#">This is a link</a>
</div>
```

css,

```
.messageContent {
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: lightBlue;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
}

.messageContent:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

What I am doing is placing an absolute `span` tag inside of the parent to act as the color overlay. When the parent is hovered the `overlay` child will become active by increasing it's opacity.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/D4qLC/1/)

Comment: No problem! Best of luck in your design mate.

Comment: And text, like "Drag and drop attachments here", goes in the span.

Comment: I made a few changes so refer to the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/D4qLC/6/. I gave the background your rgba color and then used display none -> display block for the hover state.

Comment: Was working on something similar at the same time. Your's is better.

Comment: Why thank you. :] Good luck mate and hopefully your design goes well!

Comment: The ONE solution that I found that worked with my layout of having many children to messageContent is [dragout](https://github.com/dancork/jquery.event.dragout).  I am showing the span layer over my form when I drag hover a file over the form.  Drag hover does NOT work as nicely as mouse hover. (Dragleave fires when you move over a child element with no new dragenter for that child element.)


[I found dragout here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867506/dragleave-of-parent-element-fires-when-dragging-over-children-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it.

```
<div id='msgBox'>
   <div id='blueBox'>

   </div>
   <div id='msgContent'>
       ... all the message contents, buttons, etc.
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#blueBox {
  background-color: #FFD090;
  opacity: 0.0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#msgBox").hover(function(){
    $("#blueBox").css({top:$(this).css("top")}).height($(this).outerHeight()).width($(this).outerWidth()).animate({opacity:0.6});
},function(){
    $("#blueBox").animate({opacity:0}).height(0).width(0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/54cx7/2/

Comment: Thanks, Michael!  This works too.  Went with the css version.

Comment: One thing to consider about both of these solutions is being able to turn it off, if you want the user to be able to select the text. In a jQuery solution, you can set a variable (`isFileDrag=true`) elsewhere, and then modify the hover statement to only show if `isFileDrag==true`

Comment: Thanks, for that too.  As shown, with just a `:hover`, yes it'd be a problem.  I was just using that for demo purposes.  I'm using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) which fires events `dragenter` and `dragleave`.  I'll probably have listeners to those which use jQuery's `addClass` to turn the overlay on and off.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that since content is a child of bluebox, then it inherits the 0 opacity.